# Cannot Dismiss alert in Azure Security Center via REST operation. UnsupportedResourceOperation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-security, azure-rest-api, windows-defender

I have Azure Storage with Windows Defender. When a file/component uploads with malware we have alerts in the Azure Security Center. I use Azure REST API to read and process that malware automatically. We have a custom workflow to process them. At the end of the processing, we want to remove the alert so that in the future we do not get them.

I use [List By Resource Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/securitycenter/alerts/listbyresourcegroup) to list out the alerts. I am using the  [Update Resource Group Level Alert State To Dismiss](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/securitycenter/alerts/updateresourcegrouplevelalertstatetodismiss) to change the state of the alert.

To call the API to update the status of the alert, I am forming the POST URL as follows. I took the highlighted part from the List REST call as shown in the picture.

[image]

Then I add the following before and after that.

> **https://management.azure.com**<*the id value from the above*>**/dismiss?api-version=2020-01-01**

I then make a POST request to that URL using a .Net Core 3.1 application (using the `HttpClient.PostAsync` from `system.net.http` namespace). What I am receiving is a 400 HTTP status code with "UnsupportedResourceOperation" in the body as an error code. The full response body is showing below:

[image]

The error message seems misleading. I find this answer [Dismiss Security Center Alert using Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63000195/dismiss-security-center-alert-using-graph-api) suggesting the same approach that I am following. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. My AD tenant app has a subscription contributor role.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response,
We found a bug on our side and managed to fix it, can you please try and see whether this works now?